# Are there any commands aside from ZZ and ZQ that start with Z?

Tags: key-bindings

I know that pressing `ZZ` is the same as `:x` and `ZQ` is the same as `:q!`; are there any others? There doesn't seem to be any around `:help ZZ` or `:help ZQ`, and  `:help Z` brings up the `-Z` flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `:help index`, no: `ZZ` and `ZQ` are the only two.

Comment: oh, thanks for `:help index` as well!